# Explore the levels of a categorical variable in a dataset

Tags: r, dataset, categorical-data, summary, levels

I am exploring in Rstudio a dataset about sells (continuous var.) of several fish species (categorical var.).
Is there any function that summarizes all the avaliable levels of a categorical variable without having to scroll down the whole dataset?

Comment: `table(df$fish_species)` ?

Comment: perfect, thanks